# Check Apple-Pay Price

Tags: javascript, php, applepay, applepayjs

The site has implemented payment through applePay. The problem is that the payment amount is set in javascript, i.e. can the user open the code and change the amount? How to implement verification on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Pay doesn't actually process the payment. It provides your site with a payment credential that you use to send to a payment processor.

Yes, a user can change the amount in the browser, but it only impacts what that user sees, not what is ultimately charged. The amount in the sheet is for user feedback where you can display a breakdown of the price, etc.

The best way to verify the amount is by doing this on the server side. If your site processes orders, use the items in the order to calculate the total, shipping etc. You should be able to ignore the amount coming from the client altogether.